# How to have a sequence of Windows Services

Tags: c#, windows-services

The solution I am working on requires multiple processes that are built in multiple Windows services all built using C# running on .NET.

- Service 1 : Extract data in files in a folder
- Service 2 : Analyse data and put results in image file
- Service 3 : Process images into another application
- Service 4 : Generate report

Each service runs every hour. Everything works fine.

One of the requests now is to do all services as fast as possible. Therefore I want these services to run consecutively.

How to call one service from the other or have a pipeline that runs all services one after the other.

Comment: @MitchWheat I did not get it, what is Filewatcher?

Comment: sorry meant FileSystemWatcher. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0

Comment: @MitchWheat This is excellent solution.. I followed that and it is working.. just one thing.. is there a way i can make the OnChanged event to occur only once even if many files were copied?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice

Comment: with the help of your comment and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990605/watchfolder-event-in-c-sharp-triggers-multiple-times-on-a-copy-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0) and use folders as simple queues between services. Also note, `FileSystemWatcher` might not be 100% Reliable: [FileSystemWatcher vs polling to watch for file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes)

Might need to set the [`NotifyFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter?view=net-5.0) to get the behaviour you want.

You could also add a mutex to the service, that detects if it is already running perhaps, and consumes folder/file changes in one go.

There are other heavier weight, fully featured message queues, but these might be overkill for your needs.

Comment: May be worth noting that FileSystemWatcher on its own isn't always good enough to detect all changes, see answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes

Answer (score 2):

You can use a message queue. I recommend RabbitMQ. It is simple. By the your business flow each service listens its pipeline/queue. For example Service1 extracts data from files then sends a message to Service2’s queue. Service2 gets the message and runs its task, after completes its task sends a message to Service3... You can build a flow ilke this with RabbitMQ.